# Error C2075: array initialization needs curly braces

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, curly-braces

I want to reverse a 2d array of type `char` using `std::reverse()` function in the STL algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char array[10][5];

    initiate_array(array);              // this takes care of initializing array

    std::reverse(array, array + 10);    // <- error C2075

    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting this error: `C2075: '_Tmp' : array initialization needs curly braces`
which I never encountered before!

I use MSVC++ 2008 to compile my code.

Comment: You probably want a vector of strings. The problem is that the type the array is holding is another array.

Comment: @chris yeah, `array` is a pointer to an array of pointers. I want to reverse the content of this array. can't I do that?

Comment: @Jonas no it's not. `array` is an array of arrays. An array is not the same as a pointer.

Comment: @Jonas, You're in desperate need of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c. It goes into the intricacies, not just basic use.

Comment: can we see the initiate function?

Comment: @EvilTeach just a `for` loop with `strcpy(array[i], "...");` inside of it. argument of the function is `char array[][5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the problem is that arrays cannot be assigned to one another. Let's consider how `std::reverse` might be implemented:

```
template<class BidirectionalIterator>
void reverse(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        std::swap(*first++, *last);
    }
}
```

and `std::swap` needs to be able to assign whatever arguments you give it, in order to swap them. In your case you have an array of arrays; So it's trying to swap the char[5] array at array[0] with the one at array[10], which is not valid C++.

However, **in C++11 this does work as expected**; not because you can now assign arrays, but because `std::swap` has gained an overload that makes it work for arrays, effectively mapping to `std::swap_ranges`. But you should realize that this is not just swapping pointers around, it's swapping the array type individually (chars in your case).